# Casperjs script blocked on [phantom] Starting

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

When i run a casperjs script, my script is blocked on the console message [info] [phantom] Starting... I don't understand why.

My script

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
    verbose: true,
    logLevel: 'debug',
});

var login = '******@hotmail.fr';
var password = '*******';
var baseURL = 'http://fr.bazarchic.com/';


casper.start('http://fr.bazarchic.com/', function(){
    this.fill('form[action="/login/"', {
    'email' : login,
    'pass' : password
    }, true)
});

casper.then(function() {
    var pageTitle = this.evaluate(function(){
        return document.title;
    })
    this.echo(pageTitle);
});
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In fact, i simply forgot to put `casper.run();` at the end.

Comment: So much time wasted. Thanks!!

Comment: Lot of time wasted. Thanks!